# I'm working creating a rental car billing calculator. I keep getting an error message saying that mileCharge is undefined. What am i missing?

Tags: python

```
mileCharge = totalMiles * 0.25
print(format(mileCharge, "%.2f"))
# This is the line that it kicking back the error message
```

I watched a youtube video which gave step by step instructions on this particular project and my code matches his exactly as far as I can tell.  His goes through fine while mine has an error message,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "rental_car.py", line 36, in <module>
        format(mileCharge, "%.2f")
    NameError: name 'mileCharge' is not defined
```

Comment: Hello! Could you give us some more info? More lines of code? What is totalMiles?

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Here is the code before and after my error.
if rentalCode == 'B':
  mileCharge = totalMiles * 0.25
print(format(mileCharge, "%.2f"))
if rentalCode == 'D':
  averageDayMiles = int(totalMiles)/int(rentalPeriod)
  if averageDayMiles<=100:
    totalMiles = 0
  elif averageDayMiles > 100:
    extraMiles = averageDayMiles - 100
  mileCharge = extraMiles * 0.25
  
if rentalCode =='W':
  averageWeeklyMiles = int(totalMiles) / int(rentalPeriod)
  
if averageWeeklyMiles <= 900:
  mileCharge = 0
elif averageWeeklyMiles > 900:
  mileCharge = 100.00 * int(rentalPeriod)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if you have processed your first line in the console?
Your second line has an issue, but it is not name of the variable
check out this standalone code:

```
totalMiles = 5
mileCharge = totalMiles * 0.25
print(format(mileCharge, "2f"))
```

notice that the format is changed, yours throws an error